# How to force the INC and LIB path defaults for CPAN builds (cpanm+perlbrew)

Tags: macos, perl, macports, cpan

Background

Working with OS X and using `macports` for additional utilities and libraries. The `macports` are installing everything into `/opt/local`. But the default perl in `macports` is 5.12, specifying an higher version like to break many ports, so I'm using my own 5.16 perl installed with `perlbrew`.

So, I have libraries in the default `/usr/lib` (provided by Apple) but want linking XS based perl modules with the `macports` provided libs and includes at `/opt/local`.

Now the question, when installing modules with `cpanm` (into my perlbrew's perl tree), is here some way how to specify globally the **default search path** for libraries and includes for `cpanm` (to the modules build process) to search `/opt/local/{lib|include}` at first?

AFAIK the `cpanm` havent any switches for this, so maybe, some ENV variables? Or any simpler solution as edit every Makefile.PL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install half manually. Run `cpanm --look Some::Dist` and supply the appropriate [`INC` and `LIBS`](http://p3rl.org/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#INC) or [`--include_dirs` and `--extra_compiler_flags`](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aAPI#include_dirs) to the build tool on the command line to configure, then finish off with the build, test, install steps and close the subshell.

Alternatively, if you need to fully automate this, then use a full-featured CPAN client instead of cpanm. For example, run the [cpan shell](http://p3rl.org/cpan) and [configure `makepl_arg` and `mbuildpl_arg`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Config-Variables). This is then supplied to subsequent installations (instead of just one, as above).

Comment: the cpanm --look Some::Dist suggestion worked for me for a similar problem